# How to print the content of a nested std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-map

I'm trying to print all the content of an `std::unordered_map` specified like this:

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unordered_map<uint64_t,uint64_t>> m;
```

After adding things in the map, I tried the following:

```
for (auto it=map.begin(); it!=map.end(); it++) {
    cout << it->first << it->second << endl;
}
```

but it is not working.

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have nested `std::unordered_map`, following should work:

```cpp
for (auto const& i : m) {
    for (auto const& j : i.second) {
        std::cout << j.first << " " << j.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user13369031 glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the nested map as well. And when you work with maps it is very convenient to use a range-based for on top of a structured binding. To avoid these cryptic `first` and `second` things:

```
for (const auto& [key1, value1] : map)
    for (const auto& [key2, value2] : value1)
        std::cout << key2 << " " << value2 << std::endl;
```

It works only in C++17 though. If you cannot use it, then you have the answer by NutCracker.

Answer (score 1):

> How to print the content of a nested std::unordered_map?

To print nested [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) use nested [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

```
for (auto const& i: m) {
    std::cout << "Key: " << i.first << " (";
    for (auto const& j: i.second)
        std::cout << j.first << " " << j.second;
    std::cout << " )" << std::endl;
}
```

However, if you want to modify the container's elements:

```
for (const& i: m) {
        for (const& j: i.second)
            // Do operations
}
```